# Unit testing framework for ionic2/angular2/cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, unit-testing, ionic2

I am currently developing an app using

- Ionic2
- Angular 2
- Cordova

IDE IO am using is Visual Studio Code.

I need some good suggestions for industry standard unit testing framework for above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

- Jasmine to implement your unit tests
- Karma to automate the run of tests within browsers (phantomjs, chrome, Firefox, ...)

They are classical with Angular2 development and Ionic2 is based on Angular2.

The following article will provide interesting hints at this level:

- http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2016/01/testing-angular-2-with-karma-and-jasmine/

Comment: How does this address the requirement for testing the app as it runs on the mobile device? Or is that not relevant?